Why are the transmission spectra affected by the bias voltage?
As I mentioned in my previous question siesta: current-voltage threshold value is not consistent with the band gap value,
at different bias voltages, we have different transmission spectra.
Why are the transmission spectra affected by the bias voltages?

Because a bias voltage will change the electrostatics, thus changing the electronic structure. And the transmission function is directly related to the electronic structure.
Imagine the contrary, if applying a bias would not change the transmission spectra? What would this mean? It would mean that from any ground state calculation, one could calculate the current for any applied bias. Clearly that isn't how physics works.

Thank you! Sir! That solved my question!
